# Elastic Beanstalk Environment health set to RED but Causes button is disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm very new to AWS. When trying to deploy a web app my environment's health gets set to RED without any additional information in the event table. The "Causes" button is disabled too so I can't further investigate the reason for this health status. Does anyone have an idea why this button is disabled and where I can get more information to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: See if any instances were created. Then you can log into the instance and see what is going on. Also you can try checking the logs. If you used the eb aws command line tools, you can just type "eb logs" in the same directory you typed "eb deploy". Or you can grab the logs from the console. Hope that helps.